# How do i go about removing 51365 from a string?

Tags: php

Just wondering if you can help me out with something. I have a string with a series of numbers like 58498, 53980, 84578. Always 5 numbers in the series. Whats the best way to go about removing these?

Comment: What is the best way to eat a hot dog?

Comment: for me its on a bun with Ketchup and Mustard. You?

Comment: @Col. Shrapnel I prefer the OO approach, for extensibility and maintainability, but functional methods have great advantages in conciseness.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could do it with a regex.

```
$new_string = preg_replace("/\d{5},?/",'',$string);
```

Comment: Note that this would also match 6 digits though.

Comment: @Blair - um ... not it won't {5} is 5 digits and no more. the ,? is to remove trailing commas if they exist.

Comment: Correct, however 123456 would still match, as you don't specify that there cannot be a digit before or after it. Your code would match both (12345)6 as the , is optional and also match 1(23456) as leading digits are allowed. I could have also said that it would match 38 digits.

Comment: `$new_string = preg_replace("/(^|\s)\d{5}(,?|$)/",'',$string);` would probably be more appropriate. Match the start of the string, or a space, 5 digits and then a comma or the end of the string.

Answer (score 1):

`preg_replace` ([php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)).

You can find the 5-number strings using the pattern: `/\d{5}/g` and remove each occurrence.

Use it like this:

`$string = preg_replace("/\d{5}/g", "", $string);` (the g is for global (all occurrences))

If you want to get them (not remove them) then you should use:

`preg_match` ([php doc](http://php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php))

Use it like this:

```
$matches = array();
preg_replace("/\d{5}/g", $matches);
foreach($matches as $match) {
    // do something with each $match
}
```

Comment: In PHP (stupidly IMHO) you don't need the g flag  because preg_replace replaces all by default.